# How to determine if a file is a text file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Given a file resource, I would like to tell if its content type is text based, i.e. is not a *binary* file.

```java
IFile file = ...
IContentType contentType = IDE.getContentType( file );
boolean textBased = ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pre-defined text content type that can be obtained via the `IContentTypeManager.CT_TEXT` constant. All content types that are *a kind of* this content type are text-based content types.

```java
IFile file = ...
IContentType contentType = IDE.getContentType( file );
IContentType textContentType = Platform.getContentTypeManager().getContentType( IContentTypeManager.CT_TEXT );
boolean textBased = contentType.isKindOf( textContentType );
```

Alternatively the `ITextFileBufferManager` can determine if a path points to a text file.

```java
ITextFileBufferManager manager = FileBuffers.getTextFileBufferManager();
boolean textBased = manager.isTextFileLocation( "/path/to/file",  false );
```

The location can either be a full path of a workspace resource or an absolute path in the local file system. The second parameter determines if a file with unknown content type should be treated as text file (`true`) or not (`false`).